# how to format jsf 2.0 <f:selectItems/> with date value from List

Tags: java, datetime, jsf, formatting, jsf-2

Im using jsf 2.0 to develop app where user has to select (using radio button) a date from the list of possible choices. List of dates is a managed bean property of type List< java.util.Date>. Im using facelets

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{banner_backing.selectedInterval}" border="1" layout="pageDirection">
        <f:selectItems value="#{banner_backing.avaliableIntervals}" var="interval">                    
                </f:selectItems>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

to display radio buttons.

Here is my question:
how to format selectItems label and value in a patter other then default (Fri May 28 00:00:00 CEST 2010), like 'HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does f:convertDateTime not convert labels of p:selectOneMenu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603632/why-does-fconvertdatetime-not-convert-labels-of-pselectonemenu)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can do the conversion in xhtml using jsf.
One way is to use `SimpleDateFormat` class in your bean and format values in bean itself and add it to the list `avaliableIntervals`

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Thx for reply :)
Looks like Im gonna have to do it that way.
Im surprised this feature is lacking, even the old struts had it

Answer (score 1):

Use a backing bean method to return a list of `SelectItems`, populated from your list of allowed `Dates`. Format the date as you like when you create the list of `SelectItems`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{banner_backing.selectedInterval}" border="1" layout="pageDirection">
     <f:convertDateTime type="date" dateStyle="short"/>
     <f:selectItems value="#{banner_backing.avaliableIntervals}" var="interval"/>                    
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

you can use pattern="" to do almost anything with the date.