# Why does f:convertDateTime not convert labels of p:selectOneMenu?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, converters

Why is my `List<Date>` not getting converted? The `<p:selectOneMenu>` items pattern looks like
`Thu Mar 01 00:00:00 BRT 2012` instead of the desired "MM/yyyy".

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{report003.selectedMes}">
  <p:ajax update="pesquisaThomas" listener="#{report003.loadPesquisa()}" />
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="[Todos]" itemValue="" />
  <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/yyyy" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{report003.pesquisaMeses}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Please edit and improve your question. You forgot to elaborate "doesn't work". What exactly did you expect? What exactly happens instead? Didn't it show the labels(!) the way you expeceted? Or did it generate a conversion or validation error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conversion applies to the item **value** only, not to the item **label**. The label is just presented using the default [`Date#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) pattern.

Your best bet is *either* creating a `List<SelectItem>` instead of `List<Date>` wherein you convert the item labels yourself,

```
List<Date> availableDates = ...;
List<SelectItem> selectItems = ...;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");

for (Date availableDate : availableDates) {
    selectItems.add(new SelectItem(availableDate, sdf.format(availableDate)));
}
```

*or* using `<f:selectItems var>` with an EL function in the `itemValue`. For example, the [OmniFaces `of:formatDate()`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Dates) (or [homegrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174#7080174) one).

```
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableDates}" var="date" 
    itemValue="#{date}" itemLabel="#{of:formatDate(date, 'MM/yyyy')}" />
```

This problem is by the way not specific to `<p:selectOneMenu>`, you would have exactly the same problem when using the standard `<h:selectOneMenu>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

managed bean

```
private SimpleDateFormat sdf;
(...)

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");
}

public SimpleDateFormat getSdf(){
    return sdf;
}

public void setSdf(SimpleDateFormat sdf){
    this.sdf = sdf;
}
```

xhtml

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{report003.selectedMes}">
    <p:ajax update="pesquisaThomas" listener="#{report003.loadPesquisa()}" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="[Todos]" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{report003.pesquisaMeses}"
                   var="mes" itemValue="#{mes}"
                   itemLabel="#{myMB.sdf.format(mes)}" />
```